# Entity Framework Creating Table at Runtime

Tags: database

I am practising Entity Framework and Databases and I have a question. Below you can find the Entities that I am writing:

***Car Rental Program***

Car →       CarMake, KM, EngineCC, Age

**Client** →    Car, ??

Corporate → Contact, Fax

Private →   Contact, Surname*

**INTERFACES & OTHERS**

Enum CarMake { Audi, BMW, Renault, Volkswagen, Toyota }

IAddress →  Address1, Address2, City, Postcode/ ZIP code, Country

IContact →  Name, Address, Telephone, e-mail,

Now, when the user is using the program he will have to select what kind of Client he wants to initialize. So the table can have a relation with two entities: either Corporate or Private. But I can't decide this here since it depends on the runtime.

Should I make a One to Zero/one relation for both **Client - Corporate** and **Client - Private** and then configure the rest in winforms?
What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried to do this. Questions without code has no use.